# Use https in aws for flask api without purchasing domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, flask, amazon-ec2, https

I have made a flask application to use only as API. I have hosted it on aws using nginx and gunicorn. I intend to use the API to run my android application. There is a part in the application where i have to download something using Android Download Manager, but it only downloads things hosted in https domains. So i want to make my application https instead http. But every tutorial shows me a way with a purchased domain. I dont have much information on it yet, but I cant get an SSL Certificate from amazon without purchased domain name(which is pointless for an API). I just want to know how can I do this? How can I make my nginx server listen to https requests?

I have hosted it on aws using nginx and gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a domain name to get ssl on AWS. 
It is not allowed in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

One part of HTTPS is encryption, the other part is identity verification. What you're asking for is impossible since it is required that you have to verify your domain name. Without this no Certificate authority will sign a certificate. You cannot have publicly valid certificate if it's self-signed. ACM (Amazon Certificate Manager) an AWS service, will not allow you to create a certificate without a valid domain name.